# HttpWebResponse con Error 401

Tags: php, c#, api

Estoy intentando realizar una consulta a un API usando Authorization con este código en PHP y funciona correctamente, obtengo la respuesta en json y estado 200. Pero cuando realizo la llamada en C# obtengo siempre Error 401, el codigo c# lo pongo mas abajo...

```
    $curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "{host}/{url}",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Accept: application/json",
    "Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJ....chorro_access_token"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
```

Este es el codigo en .Net y justo al lanzar GetResponse ocurre una excepcion con el mensaje 401. decir que los valores {host} y {url} es el mismo en los dos bloques de código, la url se monta igual y el access_token es el mismo...cualquier información es bienvenida.

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Method = "GET";
            string token = "Bearer " + access_token;            
            request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, token);
            request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept,"application/json");            
            HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

Answer (score 0):

Para invocar a una api usando c# recomendaria utilices

[HttpClient Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8)

entonces el codigo seria algo como esto

```
string response = "";
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "token");

    HttpResponseMessage result = await client.GetAsync(requestUrl);
    if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        response = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

**Referencia**

[HttpClient GetAsync, PostAsync, SendAsync in C#](https://carldesouza.com/httpclient-getasync-postasync-sendasync-c/)

[Adding headers when using httpClient.GetAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29801195/adding-headers-when-using-httpclient-getasync)

Comment: Saludos Leandro, por lo que veo HttpClient es un wraper de HttpWebRequest, la diferencia de o que tengo entonces con lo que pones, seria hacer la llamada asincrona, pero ¿puede influjir eso en que el error devuelto sea 401 que indica acceso denegado?